# How to handle string that looks URL encoded in REST URI

Tags: javascript, web-services, http, url, rest

Hey so I'm having trouble figuring out how to include something that looks URI encoded but in fact must be treated literally in my RESTful URL.  For example, say I had an endpoint on my server that looked like this:

```
/something/:value
```

Then from my client code, I want to make a GET request to:

```
/something/some%20value
```

On the server, I want ":value" to be the literal string "some%20value" and NOT "some value".  How do I properly encode the request URL to ensure the server treats it as such?  I should also mention that not all request URIs will have these potential URL encoded values in them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't that up to the client?

Comment: Is what up to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I may have figured this out.  It seems to work if I just encode the percentage sign in my URLs.  URL code for % is %25.  So for example the correct URL would be:

```
/something/some%2520value
```